# Perl- Need to continue with next line before previous is finished

Tags: perl, line

I have a small script that executes a batch statement and begins to download a stream. The batch statement will continue until it is stopped. I need the script to continue to the next line (where it sets the location of the file being created), as is it will only continue when the previous line of code (the batch statment) is finished. Is this possible?  Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test_path= "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:8000/test/stream1.m3u8";
my $status = system("batch statment here");                
print "Location: $test_path\n\n" or die "can't do it:$!";
```

Comment: See [How do I start a process in the background](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-start-a-process-in-the-background%3f) from perlfaq8.

Comment: Windows 7 professsional

Comment: Did you mean the output from `print` to be consumed by the process you started?

Comment: The output for the print will not be consumed by the process. The process creates a video file in real time. Once the batch file is started I need to execute the next line. I do not need any return values from the batch file for the remaining Perl script. Just need to execute the next line to direct the users video player to the path where the batch file has created the file.

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix-like system, you can run the command in the background

```
system("batch statment here &");
```

but then, you won't have the return status from the batch command, but from the shell.

Comment: As suggested I tried running it in the background but the next line still does not execute.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I start a process in the background](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-start-a-process-in-the-background%3f) in perlfaq8 lists several modules that you can use, but [Proc::Background](http://search.cpan.org/~bzajac/Proc-Background-1.10/lib/Proc/Background.pm) seems to be the simplest for this particular task. It works on both Windows and *nix, so you shouldn't have to change your Perl code if you switch OS's (although you would have to change the external command you call). Run it like this:

```
use Proc::Background;

my $proc = Proc::Background->new($command, $arg1, $arg2)
        or die "Failed to run $command: $!";

# Do stuff

my $wait_status = $proc->wait;
my $exit_code = $wait_status >> 8;
print "$command finished with exit code $exit_code\n";
```

The `new` method works much like the builtin `system` command. You can either pass a list of parameters with the command name followed by its arguments as I did above (does not invoke a shell); or pass a single string containing the command and its arguments (does invoke a shell).

On Windows, you can pass either an absolute or relative path to your executable:

> If the executable's name is an absolute path, then new
>       checks to see if the executable exists in the given location
>       or fails otherwise.  If the executable's name is not
>       absolute, then the executable is searched for using the PATH
>       environmental variable.  The input executable name is always
>       replaced with the absolute path determined by this process.
>
> In addition, when searching for the executable, the
>       executable is searched for using the unchanged executable
>       name and if that is not found, then it is checked by
>       appending `.exe' to the name in case the name was passed
>       without the `.exe' suffix.

Note that at some point you will have to call `$proc->wait` if you want to get the exit status of your batch command. If the process is still running, you will have to wait for it to finish (surprise, surprise). However, you can postpone this step until the end of your script and get some other work done in the meantime.

If you need to kill the process, you can use `$proc->die`, which returns `1` if the process goes away or was already dead and `0` otherwise.

You can also set the `die_upon_destroy` option to `new` in order to kill the process when the corresponding `Proc::Background` object is destroyed:

```
my $proc = Proc::Background->new({ die_upon_destroy => 1 }, $command, $arg1, $arg2);
$proc = undef;  # $command killed via die() method
```

Be aware of how this works with lexical scope:

```
{
    my $proc = Proc::Background->new({ die_upon_destroy => 1 }, $command, $arg1, $arg2);
}
# Lexical variable $proc is now out of scope, so $command is killed
```

You can also limit the time an external command can run using `timeout_system` instead of creating a `Proc::Background` object with the `new` method:

```
my $wait_status = timeout_system($seconds, $command, $arg1, $arg2);
my $exit_code = $wait_status >> 8;
```

The process will be killed when the timeout expires.